# Updating all the nodes with single cypher query

Tags: apache-age

Consider that I'm working on a graph database and there are some nodes at some label i.e labe14 and now what I want to do is to update the properties of all the nodes and add the another one at once to each of them. How could it be done?

To add or update the property of a single node I know I can use this command:

```
    MATCH (n:label4 {id: 123})
SET n.newProperty = 'new value'
```

However how to do this for many nodes at once using a single Cypher Query?

Hoping for a great help!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your MATCH clause as follows:

```
  MATCH (n:label4)
  SET n.newProperty = 'new value', n.newProperty2 = 'value'
  RETURN n
```

This will match all nodes with label4, update and then return them.

Answer (score 0):

With the more recent version (1.3.0) you can update like as in a map.

As so:

```
MERGE (n:label1)
SET n = {
    prop1: 'Prop 1 value',
    prop2: 'Prop 2 value'
    }
RETURN n $$) as (v agtype);
```